# Routes with Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I know how to set up routes for the most part but instead of listing out 50 or so different routes for only one thing I want to change is redundant.

I havemy file system setup like this for my codeigniter application.

```
-application
    -controllers
        -admin
            login.php
            register.php
            dashboard.php
```

As of right now when I go to the following site it shows up the way it should.

```
http://www.mysite.com/admin/(login,register, dashboard)
```

However I'd like to manipulate the route to appear as the following without having to change the name of the folder in the file structure.

```
http://www.mysite.com/my-project/(login,register, dashboard)
```

Answer (score 1):

Is "my-project" a permanent part of your siteurl, for every single page? Then change your base_url() in the config.

Otherwise:

if your base_url is http://www.mysite.com

and you want to go to http://www.mysite.com/my-project/login

then you set the route to be:

$routes['my-project/(:any)'] = 'admin/$1';

or if only for those three:

$routes['my-project/('login'|'register'|'dashboard')] = 'admin/$1';

SHOULD work, although I don't have a handy way to test at the moment

Comment: Yes this is great however for some reason I don't understand why its not working. For some reason its giving me the 404 error. I tried doing $routes['my-project/(:any)'] = 'admin/$1';

Comment: I'm trying to understand why $route['my-project/login'] = 'admin/login'; works but $routes['my-project/(:any)'] = 'admin/$1'; doesn't.

Comment: can you paste up your entire routes code - sounds like something else might be interferring

Comment: Sadly enough I don't have anything inside the routes file. Nothing I've added.

Comment: then I think perhaps a syntax error or something; that route should work fine. You may want to go to IRC #codeigniter channel & talk to some people